# How to assign a negative value to a Formula based on a checkbox value in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracleforms

I have a tabular transaction form with a checkbox for Buy/Sell, quantity, price, extended_price (Formula of quantity * price) and extended_price_total (Summary of extended_price). When the checkbox on the tabular form is set to Buy, extended_price is positive, and Sell means it’s negative.

Earlier I attempted to make a post -query trigger, but I have been told to simply create a hidden dummy item and add this item to my formula (quantity * price* dummy).

Can anyone help me as to how I go about creating a dummy item which will assign itself a value of 1 or -1 based on a separate checkbox item in my data block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger on the checkbox item:

```
:block.dummy := case when :block.checkbox_item = 'A'  -- or whichever value you chose to
                          then 1                      -- represent checked checkbox
                     else -1
                end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a dummy item?  Just set the checkbox to have a value of 1 when checked and -1 when unchecked.  Then add a When-Checkbox-Changed trigger with the formula, replacing "dummy" with the name of the checkbox.

Or if the values for the checkbox are predetermined, you can still skip the dummy item by putting the formula in the When-Checkbox-Changed trigger using a CASE or IF to multiply by 1 or -1, accordingly.